# Split values to multiple row on MySQL

Tags: mysql

Here is my data in mysql table:

```
+---------+-------------------+------------+
| ID      | Name              | Class      |
+---------+-------------------+------------+
| 1, 2, 3 | Alex, Brow, Chris | Aa, Bb, Cc |
+---------+-------------------+------------+
```

I want split values to multiple rows to get data as the below format.

```
1     Alex     Aa
2     Brow     Bb
3     Chris    Cc
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You need to fix your schema. You shouldn't allow multiple values in a column let alone in all the columns.

Comment: I just want get data as above format by Mysql query.

Comment: I am telling you that you should've stored the data in table the same way you want. You should not allowed comma-separated values in table. It's a bad habit & has so many disadvantages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick is to join to a Tally table with numbers.
Then use SUBSTRING_INDEX to get the parts.

If you don't already have a numbers table, here's one way.

```
drop table if exists Digits;
create table Digits (n int primary key not null);
insert into Digits (n) values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

drop table if exists Nums;
create table Nums (n int primary key not null);

insert into Nums (n) 
select (n3.n*100+n2.n*10+n1.n) as n
from Digits n1
cross join Digits n2
cross join Digits n3;
```

Then it can be used to unfold those columns

Sample data:

```
drop table if exists YourTable;
create table YourTable (
  ID varchar(30) not null,
  Name varchar(30) not null,
  Class varchar(30) not null
);

insert into YourTable 
  (ID, Name, Class) values
  ('1, 2, 3', 'Alex, Brow, Chris', 'Aa, Bb, Cc')
, ('4, 5, 6', 'Drake, Evy, Fiona', 'Dd, Ee, Ff')
;
```

The query:

```
SELECT 
 LTRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( t.ID, ',', Nums.n), ',', -1)) AS Id,
 LTRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( t.Name, ',', Nums.n), ',', -1)) AS Name,
 LTRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( t.Class, ',', Nums.n), ',', -1)) AS Class
FROM YourTable t
LEFT JOIN Nums ON n BETWEEN 1 AND (LENGTH(ID)-LENGTH(REPLACE(ID, ',', ''))+1);
```

Result:

```
Id  Name    Class
1   Alex    Aa
2   Brow    Bb
3   Chris   Cc
4   Drake   Dd
5   Evy     Ee
6   Fiona   Ff
```

Answer (score -1):

Multiple values are not recommended for a one field but still if you want a solution you can split string by comma and insert to the table.

Please see this blog post which shows how to split https://nisalfdo.blogspot.com/2019/02/mysql-how-to-insert-values-from-comma.html#more

Comment: That seems like a good argument in favour of wanting to change it.